# Не работает маршрутизация в Yii2 restfull api

Tags: php, yii2, api

У меня есть проект. Создал папку api, сервер настроил так, что по адресу

```
https://api.site.com
```

Запрос идет в эту папку.

Настроил роутинг. Сделал все по этой инструкции - [ссылка](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/rest-routing.md)

Но когда я обращаюсь по адресу

```
https://api.site.com/user
https://api.site.com/users
```

получаю 404. Потратил 2 часа и не могу понять почему

Comment: Напишите в вопросе настройки компонента `urlManager` в конфигурации вашего приложения и как вы сделали маршрутизацию в конфигурации сервера.

Comment: Можно еще посмотреть в дебагпанели, на какой экшн в итоге уходит запрос.

Comment: Удалось решить?

Comment: да, но уже не помню как